# Changing first value of a tuple inside a tuple list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples with this format `(URL, name)`. Sometimes the URL is with the full path and I only want the www.XXXXX.yyy part, so I have a function that split the URL and returns only that part.

How can I modify all the first values in that list, to get a final list full of tuples with this format `(my_function(URL), name)`.

Ex:
I have this list:

```
my_list = [('www.url.com/index.html', 'url'), 
           ('www.website.org/id/1234/photos', '1234 Photos'), 
           ('www.test.com', 'test')]
```

And I want to apply `my_function()` to all the first values, obtaining the next final list:

```
>> print my_list
[('www.url.com', 'url'), ('www.website.org', '1234 Photos'), ('www.test.com', 'test')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `tuple` is an [immutable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-immutable) type, you cannot change the elements/content of tuples.

For your case, what you can do is generate a list with new tuples.

Try this:

```
my_list = [('www.url.com/index.html', 'url'), 
           ('www.website.org/id/1234/photos', '1234 Photos'), 
           ('www.test.com', 'test')]

f = lambda x: x.split('/')[0] 
my_list = [(f(url),name) for url, name in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[('www.url.com', 'url'), ('www.website.org', '1234 Photos'), ('www.test.com', 'test')]
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you Alex :)

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to handle url in such way (unless you are 100% sure that there will not be any urls with 'http(s)'). I think you should use `urlparse` package.

Comment: @Dexter I'm using urlparse inside `my_function` I was asking just for the modification of the tuple list, no problem ;)

Comment: In that case it is fine. Else it is something like this - https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/25/97/0d/25970defbbc7f1c19f3b2afcc638dbb4.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to fetch the domain (along with subdomains) of the URL:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

def netloc_parse(url):
    if not url.startswith('http'): 
        url = '//' + url 
    return urlparse(url).netloc

print [(netloc_parse(i[0]), i[1]) for i in my_list]
```

Output for it would be:

```
[('www.url.com', 'url'), ('www.website.org', '1234 Photos'), ('www.test.com', 'test')]
```

Thanks to [@Dexter](https://stackoverflow.com/u/5284595) for the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339332/changing-first-value-of-a-tuple-inside-a-tuple-list/42339463#comment71831081_42339463).

Comment: You should use function instead directly adding 'http' to string. Use  something like , `def netloc(url): if not url.startswith('http'):  url = '//' + url return urlparse(url)` . This will be future proof if user added any url with 'http(s)'.

Comment: This is valid too! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
def myfunction(strings):    
    return strings.split('/')[0]

output = [(myfunction(url), text) for url, text in my_list]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
my_list2 = []

for item in my_list:
    my_list2.append((my_function(item[0]), item[1]))

print(my_list2)
```

Comment: What is `function`?

Comment: @JRodDynamite: *"...I have a function that split the URL and returns only that part..."*

Comment: @SiHa - Oh okay. Should've named it `myFunction` as given in the question.

Comment: Well you can still [edit] your answer to change it :)